# Fluent Nhibernate and pluggable inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, nhibernate, fluent

Is there any way to define/expand inheritance without changing base table mapping with Fluent NHibernate? For example with Castle.ActiveRecord (based on NHibernate) you can define inheritance like this:

```
[ActiveRecord("entity"), JoinedBase]
public class Entity : ActiveRecordBase
{ 
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("entitycompany")]
public class CompanyEntity : Entity
{
    [JoinedKey("comp_id")]
    public int CompId { get; set; }
}
```

- It's possible to add or remove new subclasses without changing base entity mappings.
- When we call `Entity.FindAll()` it returns all entities (also those inherited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not right now, no. Certainly not in any way that will require *no* modifications to your parent class map.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the way, it's possible by using IClassConvention + IOC(structuremap with assembly scanning).